# Usage of ngcsv in web apps

Tags: angularjs

I really can't think of a scenario that would make me use ngcsv, it converts array to CSV file. 
What I don't understand is why the server couldn't just return a proper file instead of pass the data through client code first. If you use I'll be happy to understand why this is useful.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably it would work without access to the server since the code is all completely client side.

Answer (score 0):

I'm planning on using it in a 100% offline app that relays on LocalStorage.. so I guess there's many scenarios where it could be useful